# How to write PHP code inside of Laravel Blade template?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am writing code for a site that was done in Laravel, I know that it is not recommended to write PHP code within the Blade template, but in this instance I have limited time available.

```
@php
   if($_POST["submit"]){
        $name = $_POST["name"];
        $email = $_POST["email"];

        $missingName = "<p><strong>Please eneter your name.</strong></p>";
        $invalidEmail = "<p><strong>Invalid Email.</strong></p>";


        if($name){
            $name = filter_var($name, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        }else{

            $errors .= $missingName;
        }


          $email = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
          $email = filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
         if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){

          }else{
              $errors .= $invalidEmail;
          }
        if($errors){
            $resultMessage = '<div  class="alert alert-danger">' . $errors .'</div>';
        }else{

            $to = "leads@relevant.systems";
            $subject = "DijiJock update request form.";
            $message = "<html>
                         <body>
                         <h2 style='color:black'>DijiJock update request form.</h2>
                <p style='color:green'>Name: $name</p>
                <p style='color:green'>Email: $email</p>
                <p style='color:black'>$name has requested DijiJock updates, please forward all updates to $email.</p>
                         </body>
                       </html>";
            $headers = "Content-type: text/html";


            if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
                $resultMessage = '<div  class="alert alert-success">Thank you for the meesage!</div>';

            }else{
                $resultMessage = '<div  class="alert alert-warning">Email not sent! Please try again later.</div>';
            }
        }
        echo $resultMessage;
    }             
@endphp
```

The PHP code in the middle does not work?

Comment: So it seems that I have the right tags, but I am getting the error "Undefined index: submit "

Comment: try this if( isset($_POST["submit"]) ). you might be hitting undefined on page load which is not submittd yet.

Comment: You should be placing this code within a controller, not the .blade file...

Answer (score 3):

(Here better implement the action in the controller, you can make a helper class, bind it through a service provider, and use it)

In some situations, it's useful to embed PHP code into your views. You can use the Blade @php directive to execute a block of plain PHP within your template:

```
@php
    //
@endphp
```

which is exactly the same as:

```
<?php

?>
```

If you need to share global variables best way to do it is to use the method **share()** of the **View facade**, and do that on a **service provider**.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/views#passing-data-to-views

ex of use case: nested structure for layouts => save global variables with short names, that point to bigger name of tree traversal (+ easy to maintain when we alter the structure, do it once). ex:

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;

class ViewGlobaleVarServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    { // \/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/  <====== !
        View::share('sysAdmDashPgContainerHeader', 'system.admin.dashboard.partials.pageContainer.partials._header');
    }

    /**
     * Register the service provider.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Here i created a **new ServiceProvider**, you can use too existing one, like the **AppServiceProvider**.

If the action to execute is depending on the controller calling, better implement things on controllers, if it's view specific (internal logic). Then @php @endphp is a nice way to achieve that.

Also for sharing variable Know that we can simply use @php @phpend in a layout view (it will be available on all included partials and object that extend it). So you know the nature of @include and @yield,@extend on that matter. However that's not the best practice or recommended. What's recommended is to use the helper View::share() above.

The other way to write code is to create your **own directive**:

- Check the doc: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade#extending-blade
- Here a good example where i needed that (with multi parameter to be passed as an associative array + there is some details): https://stackoverflow.com/a/53218523/7668448

(note all you need is to create one function on a service provider, and you have your own directive, )

**And What about sharing function globally?**
Create and Use a **global helper**. By creating a file that will contain all the helpers (functions). Then either use the **co**mposer** auto loading**. Or bind an **include_once** through a **service provider**.

- composer auto-loading: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49549907/7668448
- Through service providers binding: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32422699/7668448

Answer (score 1):

Use the Controller and blade view method.

```
Mail::send('emails.YOUR_BLADE_FILE', ['user' => $user, 'request' => $request], function ($message) use ($user, $request) {
     $message->to('EMAIL_ACCOUNT', 'EMAIL_USER_NAME');         
     $message->subject('EMAIL SUBJECT');
});
```

Try to use this function . This is easy and very clean.